# Given array of strings, iterate over each and call promise based function, but wait to continue until the previous iteration finishes?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings...

```
var urls = ["http:/www.google.com", "http:/www.giantbomb.com", "http:/www.stackoverflow.com"]
```

And I need to call a function that is promise based for each one....however I want to wait for the previous one to finish before calling the next.

```
_.forEach(urls, function(url){ 
    promiseFunc(url); //BUT IT SHOULD WAIT TO CONTINUE FOR LOOP
});
```

Is there a good way to achieve this?

I am also using AngularJS.

Comment: Promise Chaining https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a modern environment, use an `async` function and a loop:

```
// In an `async` function
try {
    for (const entry of urls) {
        await promiseFunc(url);
    }
    // All done
} catch (error) {
    // Handle/report error
}
```

If you don't want to use an `async` function, use the "promise reduce" trick:

```
urls.reduce(
    (p, url) => p.then(() => promiseFunc(url)),
    Promise.resolve()
)
.then(() => {
    // All done
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another solution as well with recursion.

```
var urls = ["http:/www.google.com", "http:/www.giantbomb.com", "http:/www.stackoverflow.com"];
var executePromiseFunct: function(urls) {
  promiseFunc(urls[0]).then(function() {
    urls.shift();
    if (urls[0]) {
      executePromiseFunct(urls);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's basically what the `reduce` version does, but the critical difference is that you don't get a promise you can use to know when the loop is complete. (The above also doesn't handle errors. :-) )